# Writing any repeating decimal as a rational number in base b

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If I wanted to write a repeating decimal as a rational number in some other base how would I go about?

Is the fraction the same for any base? Can I find the fraction in base 10 then just convert the numerator and denominator to base b? E.g. if I wanted to write $0.\dot 14285\dot 7$ in base 4, I convert it to ${1 \over 7}$ in base 10 then just convert the numerator and denominator i.e. the numerator remains the same and the denominator becomes 13 for a final answer of ${1 \over {13}}$?

Comment: $\left(\frac{1}{13}\right)_{4}=\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)_{10}$ if that's what you're asking.

Comment: I want to know if that always works.

Comment: No, that does not work. Converting to base 4 amounts to writing the original fraction as a sum of powers of $\frac{1}{4}$, just as an integer to base 4 is a sum of powers of 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you do with $\frac{1}{7}$ base 10, you can also do with $\frac{1}{7}$ base 4.

1. Multiply remainder by base
2. Write div base down
3. If remainder is known, apply the repeat construct, otherwise go to step 1.

Base 10:

1. 10/7 - 1,3
2. 30/7 - 4,2
3. 20/7 - 2,6
4. 60/7 - 8,4
5. 40/7 - 5,5
6. 50/7 - 7,1
7. 10/7 -- repeat

Base 4:

1. 4/7 - 0,4
2. 16/7 - 2,2
3. 8/7 - 1,1
4. 4/7 -- repeat

So $\frac{1}{7}$ = 0.021021021021... base 4.
(Easily verified, as this is $\frac{9}{63}$)

Comment: Where does the 16, 8 and 4 come from? I don't understand

Comment: using base 4, you have to multiply the remainder by 4 instead of 10.

Comment: Think of $0.1428571. = \frac{a}{4}+\frac{b}{4^2}+\frac{c}{4^3}+...$. Multiplying by 4 will give you an integer part 'a' and a remainder. In this case a = 0 and remainder $0.5714285.. = \frac{b}{4}+\frac{c}{4^2}+\frac{d}{4^3}+...$. Multiply by 4 again gives b = 2 and $0.2857142.. = \frac{c}{4}+\frac{d}{4^2}+\frac{e}{4^3}+...$ and so on. In base 4 your fraction is 0.abc...